# Extending Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Customer_Grid

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer-grid

I'm trying to add a few custom columns to the Magento sales order create customer grid (where you either select for a customer or add a new customer prior to adding an order in Magento Admin).

I've found a few examples on how to extend the standard customers grid which I have used to create what I have so far, but I'm stuck as nothing seems to be appearing on the grid itself.

> /app/code/local/Asapsupplies/Newordergrid/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Asapsupplies_Newordergrid>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Asapsupplies_Newordergrid>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <asapsupplies_newordergrid>
            <class>Asapsupplies_Newordergrid_Model_Adminhtml</class>
        </asapsupplies_newordergrid>
    </models>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
            <observers>
                <customgrid_column_append>
                    <type>model</type>
                       <class>Asapsupplies_newordergrid_Model_Adminhtml_Observer</class>
                    <method>beforeBlockToHtml</method>
                </customgrid_column_append>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        <eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
            <observers>
                <customgrid_collection_append>
                    <class>Asapsupplies_Newordergrid_Model_Adminhtml_Observer</class>
                    <method>beforeCollectionLoad</method>
                </customgrid_collection_append>
            </observers>
        </eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

> /app/code/local/Asapsupplies/Newordergrid/Model/Adminhtml/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Asapsupplies_Newordergrid_Model_Adminhtml_Observer
{
/**
 * Adds columns to admin create new order customers grid
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Asapsupplies_Newordergrid_Model_Adminhtml_Observer
 */
public function beforeBlockToHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $grid = $observer->getBlock();
    /**
     * Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Customer_Grid
     */
    if ($grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Customer_Grid) {
        $grid->addColumnAfter('account_code', array(
            'header'    => 'Account Code',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'index'     => 'account_code',
        ), 'website_id');

        $grid->addColumnAfter('company_name', array(
            'header'    => 'Company Name',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'index'     => 'company_name',
        ), 'account_code');
    }
}   
/**
 * Adds Custom Attributes to the create new order customer grid collection
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Asapsupplies_Newordergrid_Model_Adminhtml_Observer
 */
public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    if (!isset($collection)) {
        return;
    }
    /**
     * Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection
     */
    if ($collection instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection) {
        /* @var $collection Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('account_code')->addAttributeToSelect('company_name')->addAttributeToSelect('cost_centre_code');
    }
}
Mage::log('Observer function beforeBlockToHtml called', null, 'mylog.log');
}
```

> /app/etc/modules/Asapsupplies_Newordergrid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <ASAPSupplies_Newordergrid>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends></depends>
    </ASAPSupplies_Newordergrid>
</modules>
</config>
```

If you notice something missing or any idea why this isn't updating the grid that would be great.

EDIT

Following the answers below the original issue has been resolved, however with the new module in place it's now not loading my previous edits to the customers grid.

> /app/code/local/Asap/CustomerGridAdditions/etc/config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
<modules>
    <Asap_CustomerGridAdditions>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Asap_CustomerGridAdditions>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <asap_customergridadditions>
            <class>Asap_CustomerGridAdditions_Model</class>
        </asap_customergridadditions>
    </models>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <customgrid_column_append>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Asap_CustomerGridAdditions_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>beforeBlockToHtml</method>
                </customgrid_column_append>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        <eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
            <observers>
                <customgrid_collection_append>
                    <class>Asap_CustomerGridAdditions_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>beforeCollectionLoad</method>
                </customgrid_collection_append>
            </observers>
        </eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
    </config>
```

> /app/code/local/Asap/CustomerGridAdditions/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Asap_CustomerGridAdditions_Model_Observer
{

/**
 * Adds column to admin customers grid
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Asap_CustomerGridAdditions_Model_Observer
 */

public function beforeBlockToHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $grid = $observer->getBlock();

    /**
     * Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
     */
    if ($grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid) {
        $grid->addColumnAfter('account_code', array(
            'header'    => 'Account Code',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'index'     => 'account_code',
        ), 'website_id');

        $grid->addColumnAfter('company_name', array(
            'header'    => 'Company Name',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'index'     => 'company_name',
        ), 'account_code');
    }
}

/**
 * Adds Custom Attributes to the customer grid collection
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Asap_CustomerGridAdditions_Model_Observer
 */

public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    if (!isset($collection)) {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection
     */
    if ($collection instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection) {
        /* @var $collection Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('account_code')->addAttributeToSelect('company_name');
    }
}
}
```

> /app/etc/modules/Asap_CustomerGridAdditions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Asap_CustomerGridAdditions>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends></depends>
    </Asap_CustomerGridAdditions>
</modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried your code on my local machine and its working. I can see columns in my Create order grid. Please review attached screenshot.
[image]
The only thing I can see in your code which is missing is the closing `config` tag `</config>` in both of your `config.xml` as well as in `app/etc/modules/Grids_NewOrderGrid.xml`
Please add those and check again. If you still can't see the columns, refer to the answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159348/2443)

**EDIT**
There is also another thing you can do here,
Put your Observer file in `app/code/local/Grids/NewOrderGrid/Model/Adminhtml/Observer.php`

Update your observer class with name `Grids_NewOrderGrid_Model_Adminhtml_Observer` and check if its working.
You can add a log entry in your observer function with `Mage::log('Observer function beforeBlockToHtml called', null, 'mylog.log');` to check if your observer is being called.

**EDIT**
Please update your module name in **config.xml** as `Asapsupplies_Newordergrid`

Update your model class to `Asapsupplies_Newordergrid_Model`

In event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` update class to `Asapsupplies_Newordergrid_Model_Adminhtml_Observer`
Now go to `System > configuration > Advanced` and check if you can see your module and its status is Enabled.
Clear your cache and then check.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I've checked the files and can confirm they are actually there and must have been chopped off when I copied them across to here. I will review your other answer and see if that works at all.

Comment: Thanks again for the screenshot, I can see it's working for you but still not for me unfortunately. I've edited the names to be Newordergrid instead also with no avail. I'm wondering if it's to do with the folder structure as I don't really have any other ideas.

Comment: Please check edits to my answer. Also it will be better if you can add your full file path to your question description.

Comment: I've now updated the file paths (note I've used exact locations on the files now with different names). I've also added the log into the file too but feel I may have made some errors as I'm not seeing this log either. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check updated answer. Please make sure your module is enabled because now there seems no other issue in your code.

Comment: Thanks again for the answers, I've finally got this to work and display the information I wanted. Just one other semi-related issue however, as this is now working I have a similar extension on the main manage customers grid which now doesn't display since this has been put into place. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: Do you mean your Customer grid is not working?

Comment: The grid is working, it's missing similar additions to the grid however (like account code, company name). The grid was extended in a similar way so I'm not sure if that causes any conflicts and how to get around that?

Comment: It should work. can you add your code for customer grid to look into?

Comment: I've added the code to the bottom of the original question, a mentioned it uses basically the same method from what I understand so I can only assume there is some sort of conflict?

Comment: Again your code is correct, I can see both the columns on my setup. Please update your module name from `Asap_CustomerGridAdditions` to `Asap_Customergridadditions` and then check