# Custom module problem in Docker container

Tags: magento2, module, third-party-module, docker

I am having an issue getting a custom module created with

https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/

to work properly inside of a Docker container.

I have tried containers from

```
https://github.com/alexcheng1982/docker-magento2

https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-magento
```

Both install and operate fine and when I include my module files by creating a volume I can install it just fine. The problem occurs when I add a new entry through the admin panel. I have this same module running locally on AMPPS server and it works as expected.

When deployed in default mode I get this display:
[image]

This is normal when run locally:
[image]

Here is the output of the errors produced when in developer mode:

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Testmodel\Edit\Form
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Testmodel\Edit\Form does not exist
```

Any help is appreciated.

### EDIT:

(include docker-compose.yml)

My docker-compose.yml showing how I am mounting `./modules` to `/app/code`

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  web:
    image: alexcheng/magento2
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - magento-data:/var/www/html  
      - ./modules:/var/www/html/app/code
    env_file:
      - env
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6.23
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
    env_file:
      - env
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8580:80"
    links:
      - db     
volumes:
  magento-data:
  db-data:
```

### EDIT:

(include full error)

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Testmodel\Edit\Form
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Testmodel\Edit\Form does not exist

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Testmodel\Edit\Form
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('TattcomTest\Test...', 'testmodulename_t...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:785]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_createBlock('TattcomTest\Test...', 'testmodulename_t...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:768]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->createBlock('TattcomTest\Test...', 'testmodulename_t...', array('data' => array())) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:349]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->createBlock('TattcomTest\Test...', 'testmodulename_t...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:404]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->addChild('form', 'TattcomTest\Test...') called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php:151]
#6 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container->_prepareLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:287]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->setLayout(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor#000000000bdc60ac0000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:149]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#000000000bdc66ec0000000074d4eff1#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#000000000bdc663e0000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#000000000bdc66ec0000000074d4eff1#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#000000000bdc663e0000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:352]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:89]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:224]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:237]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php:170]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php:114]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayout() called at [app/code/TattcomTest/TestModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/TestController/Edit.php:35]
#19 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#20 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#21 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php:51]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute(&TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor#000000000bdc67490000000074d4eff1#, &Closure#000000000bdc66040000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#23 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#24 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', array(), array(array('customerNotifica...', 'themeRegistratio...'))) called at [generated/code/TattcomTest/TestModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/TestController/Edit/Interceptor.php:26]
#25 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:151]
#27 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#28 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#29 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#30 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor#000000000bdc67490000000074d4eff1#, &Closure#000000000bdc60ed0000000074d4eff1#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#31 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#32 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#), array(array('adminLoadDesign'))) called at [generated/code/TattcomTest/TestModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/TestController/Edit/Interceptor.php:39]
#33 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:186]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#, &TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor#000000000bdc67490000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#39 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#41 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000000bdc633f0000000074d4eff1#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>

Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Testmodel\Edit\Form does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('TattcomTest\Test...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('TattcomTest\Test...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('TattcomTest\Test...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('TattcomTest\Test...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php:46]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock('TattcomTest\Test...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:272]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('TattcomTest\Test...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:252]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('TattcomTest\Test...', 'testmodulename_t...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:785]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_createBlock('TattcomTest\Test...', 'testmodulename_t...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:768]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->createBlock('TattcomTest\Test...', 'testmodulename_t...', array('data' => array())) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:349]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->createBlock('TattcomTest\Test...', 'testmodulename_t...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:404]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->addChild('form', 'TattcomTest\Test...') called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php:151]
#12 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container->_prepareLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:287]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->setLayout(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor#000000000bdc60ac0000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:149]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#000000000bdc66ec0000000074d4eff1#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#000000000bdc663e0000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#000000000bdc66ec0000000074d4eff1#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#000000000bdc663e0000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:352]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:89]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:224]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:237]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php:170]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php:114]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayout() called at [app/code/TattcomTest/TestModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/TestController/Edit.php:35]
#25 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#26 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#27 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php:51]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute(&TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor#000000000bdc67490000000074d4eff1#, &Closure#000000000bdc66040000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#29 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#30 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', array(), array(array('customerNotifica...', 'themeRegistratio...'))) called at [generated/code/TattcomTest/TestModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/TestController/Edit/Interceptor.php:26]
#31 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:151]
#33 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#34 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#35 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#36 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor#000000000bdc67490000000074d4eff1#, &Closure#000000000bdc60ed0000000074d4eff1#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#37 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#38 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#), array(array('adminLoadDesign'))) called at [generated/code/TattcomTest/TestModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/TestController/Edit/Interceptor.php:39]
#39 TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:186]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#, &TattcomTest\TestModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\TestController\Edit\Interceptor#000000000bdc67490000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#41 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#42 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#43 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#44 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#45 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000000bdc63c50000000074d4eff1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#46 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#47 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000000bdc633f0000000074d4eff1#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

### EDIT

(include app/code/TattcomTest/TestModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/TestController/Edit.php)

From error-

#18 Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayout() called at [app/code/TattcomTest/TestModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/TestController/Edit.php:35]

```
<?php
namespace Tattcom\SponsoredArtists\Controller\Adminhtml\SponsoredArtistsControllerAdmin;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. Get ID and create model
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Tattcom\SponsoredArtists\Model\SponsoredArtists');
        
        $registryObject = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
        
        // 2. Initial checking
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('This row no longer exists.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
        }
        // 3. Set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->getFormData(true);
        
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }
        
        $registryObject->register('tattcom_sponsoredartists', $model);
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to delete everything from /generated/code/ and run setup:di:compile ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, I have been trying every possible solution posted on stack and have yet to find an answer that works. I am completely green to docker and seeing as it runs fine under AMPPS locally I seem to think it's a setup issue and nothing with the actual code. For good measure I installed a fresh copy of magento 2.4 on my local machine and installed the custom module in the same way I am in my container.  Everything workes as expected.

Comment: I think this is permission related, I installed docker on my mac and duplicated the steps I am using on the VPS with CentOS. My module worked! So I went in and checked permissions a little closer. On my mac the `app/code` directory has www-data user and group ownership. On linux machine `app/code` directory is 1000 user and group. https://blog.gougousis.net/file-permissions-the-painful-side-of-docker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a Docker issue but rather a Linux vs OSX file naming issue.

This post describes the problem
[Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159337/custom-module-not-working-on-live-server)

After building new module with new names it is working.

```
SponsoredArtistsController > Sponsoredartistscontroller
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using mac? If so, this is tipycally a sync issue between your local and the container.

- quick fix worth trying: try to stop and restart your container.
- another fix (possibly more optimised) is to mount the generated folder so that docker does not try to sync it. This would speed up your docker setup in fact. The generated line should give you a mapping. Unfortunately, I can't test this as I am on linux and don't need the line in practice.

[image]

- also if you use docker-sync, hit the command `docker-sync log` and you might see what's in the way in your sync

Comment: My local machine is running the AMPPS server and is a Mac. However I am trying to deploy on a VPS with CentOS 8.

Comment: ok, then try to to sync your generated folder with your VPS, rsync will this fine..

Comment: I have added my docker-compose.yml to the original post, I am following these instructions for mounting the volume containing my module. https://github.com/alexcheng1982/docker-magento2#extensions-and-themes

Comment: Ok, I will try to add a volume for the generated files. As far as docker-sync I'm not sure there is a use for it according to this link https://docker-sync.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/sync-strategies.html#native-linux

Comment: agreed, docker-sync is very high maintenance. Yet, when your code is changed, it needs to go to the container.. my solution was to move on to linux just recently in fact